# Determine how an object was declared

Tags: xtext

I have this rule:

```
Room:
    'room' ('final')? name=ID
;
```

So I can declare a room in two ways:

```
room bedroom
```

or

```
room final bedroom
```

Now I'm writing a validator and I need to check if the room was declared with the word final or not. Is there a way to check this?

EDIT: This is the validator I'm writing:

```
@Check
def checkIfFinalRoom(Room room){
    println(room)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to store the information about the final keyword in the semantic model. It can be done like this:

```
Room:
    'room' (final?='final')? name=ID
;
```

Please refer to the [Xtext documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html) for details on the grammar syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
@Check
def checkIfFinalRoom(Room room){
    val declaration = room.findActualNodeFor.text.trim
    println(room.contains("final")) 
}
```